# Python Crypt Import Linux Salt

Tags: python, crypt

Having trouble getting the crypt to work for my Ubuntu salt. I can run it with an arbitrary salt but with the special salt it does not. Any help is appreciated.

This works:

```
   cryptWord = crypt.crypt('word', "HX")
   print cryptWord
   #prints salted word
```

This does not:

```
   zebra = crypt.crypt('password', "$1\$WDvKY5n\$")
   print zebra
   # prints None
```

I am trying to be able to compare the salted word to a slated password but am unable to with the more advanced salt. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us a complete example that demonstrates the problem. `print(zebra)` will of course return `None`, because that's what `print` _always_ returns… but it will print `$1d2n7Q0.r54s` to stdout.

Comment: Tried to explain it more clearly

Comment: @blankwall are u sure you are not using other variables or something else instead of the string 'password' and "$1\$WDvKY5n\$"? Here it worked fine

Comment: That is exactly what I am using will look into it more on my end. thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an invalid salt.

Although [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/crypt.html) doesn't say so, [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/cryptmodule.c#l15) makes it clear that `crypt.crypt` will return `None` if the underlying C function returns NULL. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/crypt.html) allows it to do so, and [linux/glibc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) explicitly does so when given an invalid salt.

So, what's wrong with this salt?

If you read the "Glibc notes" section on the manpage, the string `$1\$WDvKY5n\$` is going to use `1\` as its encryption method id. There's an encryption method with id `1`, but nothing with id `1\`. Plus, the salt itself is `WDvKY5n\`, but the salt is only allowed to contain characters in the set `[a-zA-Z0-9/]`.

Most likely, you printed out the salt in some way that caused the `$` characters to be escaped (for the shell?), then copied and pasted the escaped version instead of the actual string.

If that's what went wrong, just use `$1$WDvKY5n$` and everything will be fine.

If something else went wrong and the salt is irreversibly garbled, just go look it up correctly and use whatever you find.

Meanwhile, the reason this works for people on other platforms (returning `'$1d2n7Q0.r54s'` instead of `None`) is that BSD and FreeSec `crypt` (the stock implementations on most POSIX platforms besides linux) both take any salt that doesn't start with an underscore to be a traditional-crypt value, where the first two characters can be any ASCII value and the rest of the salt is just padding.